# Invalid argument supplied for foreach logical condition

Tags: field

i'm creating a plugin for conditional logic but i have this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ on line 128
```

This is the code:

```
function xwtLoadVariationSettingsFields( $variations ) {
    $fields = json_decode(get_post_meta($variations[ 'variation_id' ],'xwtvarLinkData',true));
    echo '<div class="xwtVariationFields">';
    foreach($fields as $k=>$v){
        $kParts = explode("--",$k);
        $field1 = explode("__",$kParts[0]);
        $field2 = explode("__",$kParts[1]);
        $div = '<div firstID="'.$field1[0].'" firstVal="'.$field1[1].'" secondID="'.$field2[0].'" secondVal="'.$field2[1].'" value="'.$v.'"></div>';
        echo $div;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    return $variations;

}
```

Suggest?

Comment: *Suggest?* Yes - [edit] your post to add a tag for the language you're using, to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function xwtLoadVariationSettingsFields( $variations ) {
  $fields = json_decode(get_post_meta($variations[ 'variation_id' ],'xwtvarLinkData',true));
  echo '<div class="xwtVariationFields">';
    if(is_array($fields) && !empty($fields)){
      foreach($fields as $k=>$v){
            $kParts = explode("--",$k);
            $field1 = explode("__",$kParts[0]);
            $field2 = explode("__",$kParts[1]);
            $div = '<div firstID="'.$field1[0].'" firstVal="'.$field1[1].'" secondID="'.$field2[0].'" secondVal="'.$field2[1].'" value="'.$v.'"></div>';
            echo $div;
        }
      }
    echo '</div>';
return $variations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would google `foreach`, `json_decode`, and `get_post_meta` functions. In `foreach`, `$fields` needs to be an array. My guess is that

```
$fields = json_decode(get_post_meta($variations[ 'variation_id' ],'xwtvarLinkData',true));
```

does not return an array.